# How can I get the dynamic part of any html attribute and use it in jquery selector?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to develop a comment section with jquery ajax. There, I need to assign a dynamic id to every comment button as many comments would appear with their parent posts. So I've embedded a dynamic part with the constant part, i.e.:

```
<button type="submit" class="comment" id="<?= 'commentButton_' . $post['id'] ?>" ?>" class="btn-sm btn-outline-success border-0">Comment</button>
```

Now, I need to use it in my jquery. I've been trying for a while like the following:

```
$("#commentButton_" + id).on("click", function(e) { 
 e.preventDefault();
....
```

That doesn't work.

Could anyone help me solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Well if that's your actual HTML, it's got some syntax errors in it. You have the closing PHP tag and quotation mark `?>"` twice.

Comment: Are you just trying to attach a click handler to that one element?  Or to all elements which have that "dynamic" ID and then get the ID within the handler?  Edit: Since two users with the same name are replying to you, your replies may get confusing.  Please be clear :)

Comment: Whoa another David. That confused me.

Comment: Why not select by the common class instead?

Comment: Thank you. @Taplar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change how you're doing this slightly.

If you use a common class for all comment buttons (as suggested by Taplar) then you can use that to prevent default actions and assign a custom function.

You can store your `$post['id']` in a data attribute and easily access is from within a script.

For instance - add the data attribute as below, and a new class `comment-button`, I've also combined your two class definitions into one:

```
<button type="submit" id="<?= 'commentButton_' . $post['id'] ?>" data-postid="<?=$post['id'] ?>" class="comment-button comment btn-sm btn-outline-success border-0">Comment</button>
```

And your JQuery could be:

```
$(".comment-button").click( function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   postID = $(this).attr("data-postid");

});
```

A working demo:

```js
// Add event trigger using the new common class
$(".comment-button").click(function(e) {

  // Prevent default actions
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get Post ID from new data attribute
  postID = $(this).attr("data-postid");

  // Prove that we've managed it
  console.log(postID);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id=" commentButton_1" data-postid="1" class="comment-button comment btn-sm btn-outline-success border-0">Comment on Post 1</button>

<button type="submit" id=" commentButton_2" data-postid="2" class="comment-button comment btn-sm btn-outline-success border-0">Comment on Post 2</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Oliver Trampleasure

Comment: No problem, if you're happy with the answer please accept it by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: But this time, I got this problem:                                                                                          Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:46)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)